# Flash don't play in WebView for FLV

Tags: android, flash, webview, flv

I want to play a .flv video in a webview but it did not work. I enabled plugins and JavaScript, `set android:hardwareAccelerated="true"`. In webview there is the blue rock beause of the missing Flash plugin... Can anyone help me. thanks in advance

```
webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);

webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);

webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);

//load vidoe into WebView

webView.loadUrl(Uri.fromFile(flvHtml).toString());
```

Comment: which sdk version are you using?

Comment: @Diffy I compiled it with Android 4.2.2 SDK API 17 Rev. 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flash content wont play in Andriod, at least on higher versions since Adobe has stopped the support for it. On lower version devices, you can insatll Flash Player from their archives and it will play. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23327459/flash-support-on-android) was my question yesterday.

Comment: Now I compiled my app with Android API 7 Android 2.1 and tested it on genymotion emulator runnig Android 2.3.7 but flash still did not work... I do not know why, any idea?

Comment: Now do u have flash on your emulator?. Its better if u test it on a device with falsh installed

Comment: I compiled it as Android 2.1 and tested it at HTC Desire running Android 2.3.7, still not work... here some screenshots [here](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3606/jlyyd5bu_png.htm) and [here](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3606/jc2k75hi_png.htm) any idea why it does not work? do you have a sample code to check if the mistake is because of code?